# "Metrics per instance (Apps)" on Azure App Service not showing data for some sites

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have about 10 web apps on an S2 Azure App Service Plan (23 if you toss it the staging slots and a few Function Apps hosted in the Plan). If I go to "Metric per instance (App Service Plan)", I get nice CPU and memory charts for some of the apps, but most of the apps don't return any data.

For the ones that don't return any data, if I go into "Metrics per instance (Apps)" on the app itself, there's no data there, either, though the apps are otherwise running fine.

Here's an example of a working app:

[image: Working]

And here's one that ain't:

[image: Not Working]

I've clicked through the Web Apps themselves and can't figure out what the issue is. If I go into Kudu, I can see the processes in Process Explorer as usual.

I only had to go in there because I had a memory leak and needed to figure out who the culprit was, but without the data I had to figure it out by looking at Process Explorer in Kudu. I'd say it was probably always like this, though.

Any ideas what might cause this sort of thing?

Comment: For memory leak, you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/02/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services/) for getting a full memory dump in azure app service. Also, you could try to leverage the Crash Diagnoser extension, more details you could refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/01/20/how-to-capture-dump-when-intermittent-high-cpu-happens-on-azure-web-app/).

Comment: Thanks, I did figure out the memory leak from a Kudu dump. Now I’m just interested in why the charts don’t work for certain apps.

Comment: We have similar issue for app service plan migrated from another subscription.

Comment: @samfromlv Ah, mine was migrated from another subscription as well. Guess it's just busted forever....